Split a Pandas column of lists with different lengths into multiple columns
I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like:
ID  result
1   [.1,.5]
2   [.4,-.2,-.3,.1,0]
3   [0,.1,.6]

How can split this column of lists into two columns?
Desired result:
ID  result_1 result_2 result_3 result_4 result_5
1   .1       .5       NaN      NaN      NaN
2   .4       -.2      -.3      .1       0
3   0        .1       .6       NaN      NaN

I have digged into it a little and found this: Split a Pandas column of lists into multiple columns
but this only seems to apply to list with a constant number of elements.
Thank you so much in advance.

The post you linked to has all the answers, so I think this thread should be marked as duplicated, but I've left the code as an answer because I think there's a reason you linked to the correct answer and didn't reach a conclusion.

You can do this as suggested in linked post.
import pandas as pd

# your example code
data = {"ID": [1, 2, 3], "result": [[0.1, 0.5], [0.4, -0.2, -0.3, 0.1, 0], [0, 0.1, 0.6]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

answer
out = df[['ID']].join(
    pd.DataFrame(df['result'].tolist())
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f'result_{x + 1}')
)

out:
   ID  result_1  result_2  result_3  result_4  result_5
0   1       0.1       0.5       NaN       NaN       NaN
1   2       0.4      -0.2      -0.3       0.1       0.0
2   3       0.0       0.1       0.6       NaN       NaN


You can create a new data frame from the values
df = pd.DataFrame(original_df['result'].tolist()).add_prefix('result_')
df = pd.concat([original_df['ID'], df], axis=1)

Output
   ID  result_0  result_1  result_2  result_3  result_4
0   1       0.1       0.5       NaN       NaN       NaN
1   2       0.4      -0.2      -0.3       0.1       0.0
2   3       0.0       0.1       0.6       NaN       NaN


Note: This approach loses the ID column. Also .values is not required.
